# How to fix "Connection Reset" in Eclipse for HTTPS url

Tags: java, eclipse, url, httpurlconnection, connection-reset

I am trying to parse a **https** url link and getting a **connection reset** problem in eclipse , however it works in eclipse ( returns 301 response code though )
How to solve this ?
Thanks

```
try {

String url = "http://api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/search?start_date=2018-01-07&end_date=2018-01-09";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic *****************");


System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);

boolean redirect = false;

// normally, 3xx is redirect
int status = conn.getResponseCode();
if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
    redirect = true;
}

System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);

if (redirect) {

    // get redirect url from "location" header field
    String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

    // get the cookie if need, for login
    String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

    // open the new connnection again
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

    System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);

}

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    html.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

System.out.println("URL Content... \n" + html.toString());
System.out.println("Done");

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This returns a HTTP response code "301" which redirects it to a HTTPS url which in turn give s a connection reset error .

How to solve this error in eclipse , or is there a generic way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you . Found the solution . problem was related to TLS not being available in the java version i was using .
Had to switch to a higher java version .